# Computer fails to wake up after hibernate

Tags: gnome, 13.10, suspend, hibernate, wakeup

I recently fresh-installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Toshiba Satellite L455 after several unsuccessful attempts at upgrading from a previous version. After resolving several minor glitches I find myself unable to resolve this very annoying occurrence: having to completely shut down and rebooting my computer every time it goes into hibernation, whether from inactivity, or after closing the lid and opening it back up--like I used to do.

In looking at other Forum questions, someone suggested finding out some additional information in order to better address the issue, so I went ahead and obtained it, in case this may expedite attempts to resolve the question. So I ran

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

and obtained the following result:

```
*-network               
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
logical name: eth0
version: 02
serial: 00:26:22:47:7d:1c
size: 10Mbit/s
capacity: 100Mbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
resources: irq:44 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f2010000-f2010fff memory:f2000000-f200ffff memory:f2020000-f203ffff   *-network
description: Wireless interface
physical id: 2
bus info: usb@1:2
logical name: wlan0
serial: 70:1a:04:70:9b:92
capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8187 driverversion=3.11.0-18-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.69 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg monica@monica-Satellite-L455:~$
```

I'm also running Gnome Classic. But it happens in any of the desktop environments available. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think i found the resolution, installing Ubuntu on machines with Nvidia driver screws up the display. By default Ubuntu uses its own video drivers, thats why im having issues with hibernation.

I fixed it by  going to Software & Updates > Additional Drivers > change driver to NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, im using Nvidia Xorg driver VDPAU library nvidia-319, and now it hibernates and wakes up correctly. If you have other video drivers change it to whatever you have.

Comment: I don't know what I did, but after installing and switching to a different desktop manager in Gnome it hasn't happened again (I don't remember the name, and I don't want to log off to find out just yet, but when I do, I'll post here).